# optaplanner employee fairness calculation

Tags: optaplanner

How to calculate fairness of employee using Constraint streams api.

https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html

I have seen the above drools implementation in tennis solver example.

https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/581d10fb8140f37b7491d06b2bab8d5ac940d7f6/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/tennis/solver/tennisConstraints.drl

In below link it was said advanced functions, such as load balancing/fairness will be implemented in future.
How to calculate it currently using constraint streams. Is it possible to calculate?

https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2020/04/07/ConstraintStreams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConstraintStreams will support fairness, in 2 phases.

In phase 1), the tennis example applies fairness through a custom ConstraintCollector. That's being worked on here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/710
This is very similar to the state in scoreDRL.

In phase 2) (much later), there will be an out-of-the-box best-of-the-breed API on ConstraintStreams itself that does all that boilerplate for you. Think something like `from(Foo.class).groupBy(Foo::getBar, count()).loadBalance((bar, count) -> count)`

Comment: ok. Thanks. Waiting for phase2. By it seems like in above reference example, the penalize() is incorrect. Instead of calculating sqrt((a^2) + (b^2)), it is calculating sqrt(a^2)+sqrt(b^2)